# Dec 16: FED rate hike?

Tags: interest-rates, banks

Various news articles state that next Wednesday a rate hike by the FED was expected.

Yet when I look at fed-rate futures, nobody seems to expect that: http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/30-day-federal-fund.html

Can someone with industry insight elaborate on what traders expect?

Verbal answers on what is currently expected regarding the FED's rate hike are also accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fed funds futures settle into the average [daily Fed Funds effective rates](https://apps.newyorkfed.org/markets/autorates/fed%20funds) over the month. The December 2015 futures contract therefore covers the current Fed funds target rate (0-25bp) for 16 days, and then the new rate range (expected to be 25-50bp) for 15 days.

To compute the exact probability of a rate hike involves some assumptions. For simplicity, let's ignore the difference between Fed funds target rate and Fed funds effective rate. Further, let's use the mid-point of the Fed funds target *range* as the target *rate*. For the first 16 days of December then, we are talking about an average realized rate of 12.5 bp (mid point between 0 and 25 bp). As of last Friday, Dec FF contract settled at 99.78, implying a rate of 22bp. To get to this settlement price, the target "rate" for the final 15 days must satisfy
$$ 22 = \frac{12.5 \times 16 + r \times 15}{31}.$$
This suggests $r = 32.133333333 \text{ bp}$.

Now the only thing left is to compute the probability of a hike. Let $p$ be the probability of a 25 bp hike (from 12.5 to 37.5), and $1-p$ be the probability of being on hold (staying at 12.5). Then we have
$$ 37.5 p + 12.5\times (1 - p) = 32.1333. $$
This implies that the market is pricing in a $(32.13 - 12.5)/25 = 79\%$ probability of a rate hike in December.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed computation. However I am not sure how you can infer the probability from this average rate $r$. E.g. if $r>37.5$, you would have a probability $>1$. Probably you are assuming that the probability for a rate decrease is $0$, and that the rate will increase if only by $0.25$. Please elaborate on all your assumptions in the answer.

Comment: Answer updated. From Fed funds futures, you can only compute probabilities of two outcomes. It's a common assumption that the hike size is 25bp (the Fed has rarely deviated from this since 1994).

Comment: If the interest is paid at the end of December, please include time value in your calculation to be exact. Please explain the appropriate discount rate.

Comment: No discounting is involved in this exercise. The current futures settlement price is, by definition, the arithmetic average of the daily fed funds effective rate (as expected by the market).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. See also `WIRP<GO>` in Bloomberg for calculated values

Comment: @user25064 Thanks. WIRP is definitely a great tool. CME themselves provides a tool for this as well (http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/countdown-to-fomc.html), although I don't remember if I do it in the same way as them.